# Can't access the files under Windows 7 (owner is "Account Unknown")

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

I've installed Windows 7 recently and now I can't access (read, copy, delete) a lot of files.

When I try to open these files, I get the error that permission is denied (although I'm using administrator account).

When I inspect the file, owner is said to be `Account Unknown(S-1-5-21-122...`

I am able to change the owner of a file to my current account, but I still can't open it or copy it. Now it says that I don't have a permission from a current user (which makes no sense)

Some of the files are very important to me.

I booted Ubuntu Live and tried to access the files from there, but again "I had no permission".

In Ubuntu I used `umask=0000`, owner was root.root and it appeared that file was open to be read, executed and edited.  But still, I couldn't neither read, nor copy the files.

Also, I tried using "Linux Reader" which *was* able to copy files but copied files were locked as well.

Does anybody has any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Comment: What files are we talking about? How were they created?

Comment: mostly binary files (jpeg, dwg...). They were created in Windows XP. Also, in Windows Explorer, these files are listed in green color (I don't know what it means). They were "green" in XP as well, but there I could open them.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that "Linux Reader" says that "data is encrypted".

Comment: Oh, if you're using EFS, you're screwed unless you backed up the key or have access to the installation that has it. Hope you have a backup.

Comment: I don't have the key back up nor the instalation that has it. However, I do remember the username and password of user that created it. Could that help?

Comment: Also, is there any way to break the encryption (as I said, I know the password)

Comment: @user118564 It doesn't help. System creates different keys every single recreation. E.g, your "Administrator"-"pass" combination's encryption key will be A for a clean installation and it'll be B for another same o.s. clean installation. That is the algorithm, that is the desired funcionality of encryption.

Comment: @user118564 Without the key, there's no way to decrypt the files. If you have no backup of either the key or the files, you are out of luck. This behavior is by design and the reason people use EFS.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make yourself the owner and then give the owner full access to the files. Right-click on them, then Properties -> Security -> Edit.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problems you describe when I mounted another Windows computer's disk image in my Windows 7 machine.

Changing a file's ownership to access it is an operation that I personally wouldn't do, as this operation will tamper with the file's underlying file system. One scenario here is you change file ownership, then later want to access the disk in your old system - suddenly you cannot access the file system in the old environment.

Do you have an account with Administrator privileges? Under Windows 7, even if your account has Administrator privileges, Windows Explorer cannot be run with Administrator privileges ([c't Magazin has made some investigation into this issue in German](http://www.heise.de/ct/hotline/Explorer-mit-Administratorrechten-1258468.html)).

My solution is:

- If you haven't done already, activate to log in to Windows 7 as *Administrator*: In a Command Prompt with administrator privileges, execute the following command : `net user administrator /active:yes` (see http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-security/how-to-start-windows-explorer-as-administrator/a3cfdd52-695d-46b0-a617-1c9128addf01 ).
- Log in to Windows 7 with the *Administrator* account.
- Access your files.

To my observation, activating the *Administrator* account as described above won't assign a password to *Administrator*. Therefore protect the *Administrator* account as soon as possible in the account settings. Or follow http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149427 before activating the *Administrator* account.